# How to add an item to drop-down affected by list

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework

I have cascaded drop-down and list. I'm trying to add new input in as object {'name':'pizzaName','sizes':['availableSizes']} so it's added to the existing list, which is used by the user to select pizza and their available size. The problem faced is the selection of check box, because it checks them all together and doesn't update to the list. When the add button is clicked both the drop-down and check boxes assign some value and displays a empty space both in the drop-down and check box.

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0UcuvzXgNSAiNJlLXEfE?p=preview)

**Html:**

```
 Enter the new Pizza Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="newName">
    Select size availabel:
    <ul>
      <li>Small</li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected_input.checked">
      </label>

      <li>Medium</li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected_input.checked">
      </label>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button><br>
    <br>
```

Comment: Did the solution solve your problem?

Comment: @LironIlayev actually its not getting added to the customerList. So trying to figure it out. Can you post the working code in plnkr.

Comment: I'm not sure if the changes appear on your screen or not, so if they don't enter this link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/T6IoQFc6AfLIFSAVHhGV?p=info

Comment: @LironIlayev I checked the code just now in plnkr . When the input is given it display name of the pizza but the size of the pizza is not listed.

Comment: I tired to edit it, but nothing worked. can you help me with this @LironIlayev

Comment: Yep, done. Check the plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/T6IoQFc6AfLIFSAVHhGV?p=preview

Comment: If it worked mark the answer with the green V, if it didn't let me know why.

Answer (score 0):

Your project had a few problems.

1. You loaded ng-controller twice. Go to your body tag and remove the ng-controller attribute.
2. Your add function was completely messed up, I changed it to something that works now and if you have specific questions ask in the comments, I'm not going to explain every line of code.
3. Your checkboxes had the same ng-model, that's the reason why they checked and unchecked together.

**New controller**

```
$scope.newName = "";

$scope.pizzaOrder;

 $scope.customerList=[
 {name: 'mushroom', types: ['Small', 'Medium']}];

 $scope.selected_input = {small: true, medium: false};

 $scope.add = function() {
    var typesToPush = [];
    if($scope.selected_input.small)
        typesToPush.push('small');
    if($scope.selected_input.medium)
        typesToPush.push('medium');
    $scope.customerList.push({name: $scope.newName, types: typesToPush});
    console.log("Updated customerList: ");
    console.log($scope.customerList);
  };
```

Press F12 and look at the console to see that the customerList has been updated accordingly.

**New index.html**

```
<body>
    <ion-view view-title="Welcome">
  <ion-content ng-controller="pizzaShop">
    <h3> Welcome </h3>
    {{sample}}
    Enter the new Pizza Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="newName">
    Select size availabel:
    <ul>
      <li>Small</li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected_input.small">
      </label>

      <li>Medium</li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected_input.medium">
      </label>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button><br>
    <br>
    Make:

      <select ng-model="pizzaOrder" ng-options="order.name for order in customerList"></select><br>
     Type:
    <ion-checkbox ng-model="cartype" ng-repeat="sizeType in pizzaOrder.types" ng-disabled="!pizzaOrder">
    <span>{{sizeType}}</span>
    </ion-checkbox><br><br>
    <button ng-click="addEntry()">Edit</button>
    <button ng-click="home()">Back</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
  </body>
```

GL.